# JDO Entity modification is not persisted

Tags: google-app-engine, jdo

I'm using Google App Engine and I created an persistent entity using Google documentation about JDO. The class is the following:

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Message {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;

@Persistent
public long id;

@Persistent
public Text message;

@Persistent
public boolean isNew;

@Persistent
public long categoryId;

@Persistent
public boolean plus;

@Persistent
public Date lastUpdate;


Message(long id, String message, boolean isNew, long categoryId, Date lastUpdate, boolean plus) {
    this.id = id;
    this.message = new Text(message);
    this.isNew = isNew;
    this.categoryId = categoryId;
    this.lastUpdate = lastUpdate;
    this.plus = plus;
}
}
```

And than, I create the a HttpServlet with the following doPost code:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.setContentType("text/plain");
    PrintWriter writer = resp.getWriter();
    Date tenDaysAgo = new Date(new Date().getTime()-TEN_DAYS_IN_MILISSECOND);
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();

    try {
        Query queryMessages = pm.newQuery(Message.class);
        queryMessages.setFilter("isNew == True && lastUpdate <= lastUpdateParam");
        queryMessages.declareParameters(Date.class.getName() + " lastUpdateParam");
        List<Message> results = (List<Message>) queryMessages.execute(tenDaysAgo);
        for(Message msg : results) {
            msg.isNew = false;
            pm.makePersistent(msg);
        }
        //pm.makePersistentAll(results);
        writer.print(results.size() + " messages changed.");
    }finally {
        pm.close();
    }
}
```

But, when I do a post request I receive the message "3048 messages changed." and I check the database and the data is unchanged. The persistence is not working to persist the changes I made in the object. Even though using makePersistentAll( list ) or makePersistent( object ) the result is the same: no change in the database.

What I'm missing?

Thank you!

Comment: using ancient GAE JDO more than likely, and you don't have any code there to ensure commit of data (which was unsupported with v1.x GAE JDO)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a JDO transaction to keep track of changes and then commit them to issue the update SQL statements:

```
    pm.currentTransaction().begin();
    for(Message msg : results) {
        msg.isNew = false;
    }
    pm.currentTransaction().commit();
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer, but this did not work. I tried apply this without any makePersistent call, tried with makePersistent on the object, tried with makePersistentAll and none of those worked. Still missing something.

Comment: This should work, so I'm afraid we can't really help you further without more information. Please post the version of DataNucleus you are using and the debug log output - see http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform/logging.html